# extracting string from cell that contains one of many things - python

Tags: python, excel

im new to python and im using excel to perform this but my data is getting larger and i wanted to do it in python as it is way way faster.

i have an array of str that i want to extract and if the cell contains one of the str in array the str will be extracted.

i do this in excel using index match

```
=INDEX(results,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(things,A1)),0)) 

results = array of values that i want to be extracted
search = str to search in the cell
```

just to simplify,

x = [dog, cat, lion]

i want a function that would search x in an attribute

```
output

1 a quick brown   FALSE
2 cute dog puppy  dog
3 nice cat        cat
4 he saw a lion   lion
```

please note that trim left and right dont work as there is no pattern in the column where the values are searched.

Edit:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['sukuna', 'vessel', 'itadori', 'megumi']
df = pd.Series(data)

def t(x):
    for item in ['uku', 'ita', 'egu', 'rrr']:
        if item in x:
            return item
        return False

print(df.apply(t))

output:

0      uku
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series(["a quick brown", "cute dog puppy", "nice cat", "he saw a lion"])


def t(x):
    for item in ["dog", "cat", "lion"]:
        if item in x:
            return item
    return False


print(data)
print(data.apply(t))
```

Comment: thanks we are getting close. I assiged the values to a variable but it's only returning the first in the list. it's not returning other values that are present.

Comment: You should give some sample targets and your code

Comment: hi, i added edit section in the query. looking at the output it only returned 'uku'. 'ita' and 'egu' should be displayed in index 2 and 3 respectively but it returned False

Comment: I accepted the answer, I figured i shouldve used ELSE statement after the IF and now it worked. thanks